# How to merge .ts files to .mp4 in java android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, download, m3u8

I have downloaded all .ts files from .m3u8 URL, as shown below:

[image: screenshot]

Now I want to merge all .ts files into one .mp4 file.

Comment: Can you convert a single .ts file to an .mp4 file? Can you merge two .ts files to an .mp4 file?

Comment: Currently I don't know how to merge or convert .ts file(s) in mp4